# How to set system properties on `run` in Kotlin DSL

Tags: gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

What is the equivalent of this in Kotlin DSL:

```
run {
    systemProperties["spring.output.ansi.enabled"] = "always"
}
```

I tried:

```
run {
    systemProperties("spring.output.ansi.enabled" to "always")
}
```

But got:

```
* What went wrong: Script compilation error:

Line 37:     systemProperties(Pair("spring.output.ansi.enabled", "always"))
             ^ Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
                 public inline fun JavaExec.systemProperties(vararg properties: Pair<String, Any?>): JavaExec defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
                 public inline fun Test.systemProperties(vararg properties: Pair<String, Any?>): Test defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
                 public inline fun JavaForkOptions.systemProperties(vararg properties: Pair<String, Any?>): JavaForkOptions defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe kotlin is mistaking the run block for its built-in run method.
If you're referring to the application's plugin then you can configure its runtime properties with

```
application {
   applicationDefaultJvmArgs = listOf("-Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always")
}
```

see more here:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html

Comment: Thanks, this works. I still hope though somebody could come up with something resembling the gradle version, otherwise it wouldn't feel like "natural migration". :-)

Answer (score 2):

According to https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#tasks

```
tasks {
    named<JavaExec>("run") {
        systemProperty("spring.output.ansi.enable", "always")
    }
}
```