# How do I get a custom property defined in 'gradle.properties in kotlin code?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, properties, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I added a custom property in `gradle.properties` :

```
libraryVersion=0.1.0-beta
```

How do I read this in the code I'm publishing? I would like to use this value in my Kotlin library without hardcoding it.

Comment: May i ask what exactly you want to use it for , and what code do you want to read this in ?

Comment: Updated the question -- I added a custom property for my library version in `gradle.properties`. Currently I'm also hardcoding the version in the initialization of the library. I'd like to read it from the `gradle.properties` instead and pass it along as request headers in HTTP calls from the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer I was looking for after digging for a while

Here's the solution:

build.gradle.kts:

```java
import java.io.FileOutputStream
import java.util.Properties

version = "1.0.0"

val generatedVersionDir = "$buildDir/generated-version"

sourceSets {
  main {
    kotlin {
      output.dir(generatedVersionDir)
    }
  }
}

tasks.register("generateVersionProperties") {
  doLast {
    val propertiesFile = file("$generatedVersionDir/version.properties")
    propertiesFile.parentFile.mkdirs()
    val properties = Properties()
    properties.setProperty("version", "$version")
    val out = FileOutputStream(propertiesFile)
    properties.store(out, null)
  }
}

tasks.named("processResources") {
  dependsOn("generateVersionProperties")
}
```

Library.kts:

```java
private val versionProperties = Properties()

val version: String
  get() {
    return versionProperties.getProperty("version") ?: "unknown"
  }

init {
  val versionPropertiesFile = this.javaClass.getResourceAsStream("/version.properties")
  versionProperties.load(versionPropertiesFile)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You may access system properties defined in `gradle.properties`. They should have `systemProp.` prefix. Then in gradle build file you should pass it inside the program.

Here is the example of console application that prints property defined in `gradle.properties`.

File `gradle.properties`:

```
systemProp.libraryVersion=0.1.0-beta
```

File `Main.kt`:

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val libraryVersion = System.getProperty("libraryVersion") ?: ""
    println(libraryVersion)
}
```

File `build.gradle.kts`:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.5.10"
    application
}

group = "me.yunir"
version = "0.1"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation(kotlin("test"))
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "11"
}

application {
    mainClass.set("MainKt")
//    applicationDefaultJvmArgs = listOf(                              // 1
//        "-DlibraryVersion=${System.getProperty("libraryVersion")}"
//    )
}

tasks.named<JavaExec>("run") {                                         // 2
    systemProperty("libraryVersion", System.getProperty("libraryVersion"))
}
```

There are 2 variants passing system property to program:

- using "application" plugin-specific property `applicationDefaultJvmArgs`
- using `systemProperty` method for specific task

The output of the program:

```
0.1.0-beta
```

Additional links:

- https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_system_properties
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/61801906/16341604

**UPD. 1**

Or if you don't want to use prefix `systemProp.` and use gradle project properties then it will look like this for the 2nd variant:

File `gradle.properties`:

```
libraryVersion=0.1.0-beta
```

File `build.gradle.kts`:

```
...
tasks.named<JavaExec>("run") {                                         // 2
    systemProperty("libraryVersion", findProperty("libraryVersion") ?: "")
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This is close to what I want, but my code is an SDK that is consumed by other applications. There is no main function that runs.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to use a property from gradle you can do it like this

inside `app/build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

/******************/
def properties = new Properties()
try {
    properties.load(new FileInputStream(rootProject.file("gradle.properties")))
} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.warn("Properties not Found!")
}
/******************/

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        
        /********/
        buildConfigField("String", "LIBRARY_VERSION", "\"" + properties['libraryVersion'] + "\"")
        /*********/
    }
}
```

And you can take this value from BuildConfig

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        Log.d("TAG", BuildConfig.LIBRARY_VERSION)
    }
}
```