# How to get value from gradle.properties into Kotlin file?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have this constant in `gradle.properties`.

```
VERSION_NAME=0.1.0
```

I want to be able to use this value in my Kotlin files (a data class). Something like trying to pull it from `System.getProperty("VERSION_NAME")`.

This is the `build.gradle.kts` (Kotlin DSL) on the module where the data class lives

```
plugins {
    id("java-library")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm")
    id("com.vanniktech.maven.publish")
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

dependencies {
    implementation(Dependencies.Squareup.Retrofit2.retrofit)
    implementation(Dependencies.Squareup.Retrofit2.converterGson)
    implementation(Dependencies.Squareup.Okhttp3.okhttp)
    implementation(Dependencies.Squareup.Okhttp3.loggingInterceptor)
    implementation(Dependencies.Google.Code.gson)
}
```

I'm more familiar with Android where'd you have a BuildConfig static constant. However since this is not an Android project, I need to somehow get the value differently.

I tried to follow [How do I get a custom property defined in 'gradle.properties in kotlin code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69947839/how-do-i-get-a-custom-property-defined-in-gradle-properties-in-kotlin-code) which is very similar to what I need, except `tasks.named<JavaExec>("run")...` wouldn't work as the "run" task isn't found in the project.

I'm new to these types of Kotlin projects and gradle in general so I'm lost.

Comment: The Q&A you linked applies the `application` plugin, which is where the `run` task comes from. They then configure that task to set a system property when running the application. But there's two caveats about that approach: (1) You apparently are not applying the `application` plugin, and (2) that will only set the system property when the project is executed _from Gradle_ (via the `run` task). I assume you want the `VERSION_NAME` value to be accessible even after the project is deployed. You could have Gradle generate code with the value "hard-coded". Or you could configure [cont.]

Comment: [cont.] the `processResources` task to insert the value into a properties file that will be bundled with the project (it would then be a resource which you could load into a `Properties` instance using `Class#getResource[AsStream](String)`). Or you could stick with system properties if your deployment strategy allows it (e.g., the `jpackage` (Java 16+) let's you specific Java options via `--java-options`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kotlin multiplatform: Accessing build variables in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74743976/kotlin-multiplatform-accessing-build-variables-in-code)

Answer (score 0):

For non-Android projects also exists Gradle plugins, like this:

https://github.com/mfuerstenau/gradle-buildconfig-plugin